# Upper bound $ \mathbb{P}\left\lbrace \sum\limits_{\substack{i}}^{n} \dfrac{1}{\mathbf{N(x_{i})}}> \dfrac{tn}{4} +\dfrac{n}{a_{n}} \right\rbrace $

Tags: calculus, probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Is it possible to upper bound the probability bellow using Chernoff bound?

$$ \mathbb{P}\left\lbrace  \sum\limits_{\substack{i}}^{n} \dfrac{1}{\mathbf{N(x_{i})}}> \dfrac{tn}{4} +\dfrac{n}{a_{n}} \right\rbrace, $$

where, $t$ and $a_{n}$ are constants. Also, $\mathbf{N}(x_{i})=Y_{i}+1$ is a random variable with $Y_{i} \sim Bin(n-1, r_{n}).$ The terms $Y_{i}$ are mutually dependent.

The problem is that I do not know the distribution of $\sum\limits_{\substack{i}}^{n} \dfrac{1}{\mathbf{N(x_{i})}}$. I only know the distribution of $ \sum\limits_{\substack{i}}^{n} \mathbf{N(x_{i})}$ but I could not have this term in the probability.

I could also do,

$$ \mathbb{P}\left\lbrace  \sum\limits_{\substack{i}}^{n} \dfrac{1}{\mathbf{N(x_{i})}}> \dfrac{tn}{4} +\dfrac{n}{a_{n}} \right\rbrace \leq n \max_{i} \mathbb{P}\left\lbrace  \dfrac{1}{\mathbf{N(x_{i})}}> \dfrac{t}{4} +\dfrac{1}{a_{n}} \right\rbrace$$

Then, I use the Chernoff bound but the obtained bound is not tight enough. So, I want to use the distribution of term $ \sum\limits_{\substack{i}}^{n} \mathbf{N(x_{i})}$.

Comment: You never need to know the distribution of the random variables to apply Hoeffding, Chernoff, or similar bounds. You need, roughly speaking (there are strenghtenings) the summands to be independent and bounded say in $[0,1]$. This is clearly the case here (at least, based on what you write, I assume the $N(x_i)$ are independent?).

Comment: Now, Chernoff may not give you the *best* bound you could possibly obtain, so it's for you to see if what it gives is enough for what you have in mind.

Comment: I cannot apply Chernoff bound here because I do not have independence between $\mathbf{N(x_{i})}$ for each $i$.

Comment: Why do you not have independence? In your question, this is very unclear: $N_i = N(x_i)$ is "1+ a binomial." Where are the dependences?

Comment: I edited the question. I forgot the index $i$ in Y variable.

Comment: But what does that change then? If the $Y_i$'s are mutually independent, then the $N_i$ are mutually independent....

Comment: That's the problem, the $Y_{i}$ are not independent. That's why I wanted to use the distribution of the sum I already have.

Comment: Why did you not mention these dependencies in the question? that's the very core of the question.

Comment: I included this information. Thank you.